# Dart application and cross domain policy

Tags: javascript, dart, chromium, cross-domain-policy

Is it possible to disable cross domain security checks in Chromium while running dart application in Dart VM ?

The problem is that it is running on its own port, and thus my application can't send asynchronous requests to my backend which is running on another port.

Yes, I know that I can copy dart file to my backend and it will run just fine, but then I can't debug it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're after a stop gap solution, just for debugging, you can use a flag to turn it off in chrome.

```
[chromium executable] --disable-web-security
```

This is taken from this post [Disable same origin policy in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/chrome-disable-same-origin-policy).

Otherwise, the addition header in the response is the right way to go. Of course, you can swap the asterisk for a list of IP addresses if you want to improve security.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Adding `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` to response headers on backend should be enough to make cross domain asynchronous requests.