# Creating a bot/crawler

Tags: web-crawler, dart

I would like to make a small bot in order to automatically and periodontally surf on a few partner website. This would save several hours to a lot of employees here.

The bot must be able to :

- connect to this website, on some of them log itself as a user, access and parse a particular information on the website.
- The bot must be integrated to our website and change it's settings (used user…) with data of our website. Eventually it must sum up the parse information.
- Preferably this operation must be done from the client side, not on the server.

I tried dart last month and loved it…
I would like to do it in dart.

But I am a bit lost :
Can I use a Document class object for each website I want to parse?
Could be headless or should I use the chrome/dartium api to controle the webbrowser (i'd like to avoid this) ?

I've been reading this thread : https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/misc/crawler/misc/TkUYKZXjoEg/Lj5uoH3vPgIJ
Does using https://github.com/dart-lang/html5lib is a good idea for my case?

Comment: It's not in dart but spider seems interesting :
https://github.com/mikeal/spider

Comment: Hi, Jhon_, it looks like you are satisfied with the answer. Do you mind approving it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two parts to this.

1. Get the page from the remote site.
2. Read the page into a class that you can parse.

For the first part, if you are planning on running this client-side, you are likely to run into cross-site issues, in that your page, served from server X, cannot request pages from server Y, unless the correct headers are set.

See: [CORS with Dart, how do I get it to work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10456591/cors-with-dart-how-do-i-get-it-to-work)
and [Dart application and cross domain policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14021021/dart-application-and-cross-domain-policy)
or the site in question needs to be returning the correct [CORS headers](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/).

Assuming that you can actually get the pages from the remote site client-side, you can use HttpRequest to retrieve the actual content:

```dart
// snippet of code...
new HttpRequest.get("http://www.example.com", (req) {
  // process the req.responseText
});
```

You can also use `HttpRequest.getWithCredentials`.  If the site has some custom login, then you will probably problems (as you will likely be having to Http POST the username and password from your site into their server -

This is when the second part comes in.  You can process your HTML using the `DocumentFragment.html(...)` constructor, which gives you a nodes collection that you can iterate and recurse through.  The example below shows this for a static block of html, but you could use the data returned from the `HttpRequest` above.

```dart
import 'dart:html';

void main() {
  var d = new DocumentFragment.html("""
    <html>
      <head></head>
      <body>Foo</body>
    </html>
  """);

  // print the content of the top level nods
  d.nodes.forEach((node) => print(node.text)); // prints "Foo"
  // real-world - use recursion to go down the hierarchy.

}
```

I'm guessing (not having written a spider before) that you'd be wanting to pull out specific tags at specific locations / depths to sum as your results, and also add urls in <a> hyperlinks to a queue that your bot will navigate into.

Comment: Thank you for this long and detailed answer.

Comment: Yes I will very probably need to make http POST. So this is a problem that can not be easily solved? (due to CORS?)

You talked about iterates on node. But will it be possible to use a dart query? as it is in this DocumentFragment http://api.dartlang.org/docs/bleeding_edge/dart_html/DocumentFragment.html

Comment: I am asking those question but I am not sure I completely understand CORS's limits. This link : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS from you second link. Seems really clear.
I am still reading.

Comment: Basically, if your site served from foo.com requests a page or other data from bar.com, then bar.com must either provide a header explicitly allowing foo.com to request data, or provide a header allowing any site to request data (eg: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *).  Another workaround might be [JSONP](http://blog.sethladd.com/2012/03/jsonp-with-dart.html) - although you're not requesting JSON, the same method will probably still work.  Note - these are not restrictions in Dart, but in the browser security model.