# Send data between php and dart

Tags: php, ajax, post, dart

So i am trying to communicate between dart clientside and a php server side using AJAX. Since direct execution is not possible. I compiled the dart to javascript and then run it on a apache server.

json data is generated at client end, But there is no response from the the server

dart code

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:json';

void main() {
  query("#clicker").on.click.add(callServer);

}

void callServer(Event event) {
  var data ={ 'name':"sendname"}
  ,jsondata=stringify(data);
  print(jsondata);

  var req = new HttpRequest();
  req.open('post','http://localhost:8080/darttest/server.php',true);
  //req.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/json');
  req.send(jsondata);
  print(req.responseText);
}
```

php side i just echo the content received

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['name'];
echo $name;

?>
```

This is my first try at dart programming, so do let me know if this approach is even possible

Comment: What do you mean direct execution is not possible. Did you use Dartium?

Comment: Trying to call php from dart gets some error like "access-control-allow-origin"

Comment: Yes, this approach is possible (and even expected).  The `access-control-allow-origin` error is described in my answer below, and is a browser security issue rather than something that is Dart specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read the response, you have to put your code in a callback on `readyStateChange` :

```dart
var req = new HttpRequest();
req.open('post','http://localhost:8080/darttest/server.php',true);
req.on.readyStateChange.add((e){
  if (req.readyState == HttpRequest.DONE && req.status == 200){
    print(req.responseText);
  }
});
req.send(jsondata);
```

With your code the http request was not processed when you tried to read the response. You have to wait the completion of the request to read the response.

Comment: Do I have to separately activate a php-server or such? I use one but it feels that Chromium/Dartium is using its own webserver. The php script always returns `OK: 200` and no `request.responseText`.

Comment: When you use _run in dartium_ the Dart Editor will launch its own server (by default on `http://127.0.0.1:3030/`). So you have to use a separated php-server.

Answer (score 2):

Is localhost:8080 serving both the static Dart (as JS), and the php?  If not, you're likely coming across the `access-control-allow-origin` issue (which is a browser security issue).

This prevents one site posting date to another site.

Work-arounds:

1. Ensure that the site serving php returns the correct CORS headers: http://enable-cors.org/server.html
2. Serve the static Dart/JS files from the same URL (localhost:8080)

For more information, read these:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS
- [CORS with Dart, how do I get it to work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10456591/cors-with-dart-how-do-i-get-it-to-work)
- [Creating a bot/crawler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14130591/creating-a-bot-crawler/14135194#14135194)

**Update** Workaround 3 is described here (for Chrome / Dartium): 
https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/d/msg/misc/kg13xtD7aXA/uxeXXrw3CG8J

> You can add the parameter "--disable-web-security" to chrome.exe to disable cross domain check.

(Of course, this is only useful while you are developing)

Comment: Hi Chris, Im currently serving JS and PHP from localhost:8080. So shouldnt my current code should work without CORS. Thnx for the links this shd help with direct dart to php . Ill give it a shot

Answer (score 0):

this is not sending data between dart and php. this is sending data from dart to php!!!

Comment: That's a comment, but not an answer.