# Client in DART comunicate with server in PHP: access control allow origin headers missing

Tags: php, client-server, dart

This is my client:

```
  import 'dart:html';
  void main() {
    var request = new HttpRequest();
    request.open('post','http://127.0.0.1/dartphp/index.php',async: true);
    request.send("some data");
  }
```

and my server:

```
  <?php  header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://127.0.0.1:3030");                
         header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS");
  ?>
  <html><body>
  <?php 
  echo "postback";
  echo "<pre><br>post<br>";
  echo $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA;
  echo "</pre><br>";
  ?>               
  </body></html>
```

I execute the dart in Dartium on 3030 and have Apache listening on 80.
The error I get is: 
XMLHttpRequest cannot load  `http://127.0.0.1/dartphp/index.php`.  No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '`http://127.0.0.1:3030`' is therefore not allowed access.

I read the articles [Send data between php and dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14558210/send-data-between-php-and-dart) and [CORS with Dart, how do I get it to work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10456591/cors-with-dart-how-do-i-get-it-to-work) 
but in the meantime syntax has changed or the solution is not applicable to my problem,

- for the first 'on.readyStateChange.add' no longer exists
- for the second 'request.response.headers.add' is not possible, as 'response' has no 'headers' defined

What has to be changed, so that can 'request.onReadyStateChange.listen((_)' to the response

Comment: Added <? header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); ?> BEFORE the <HTML> in php and removed the request.setRequestHeader in Dart. The error that remains is the latter half: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://127.0.0.1/dartphp/index.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:3030' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: see my extended answer
I used this on a server app developed in Go to access it from Dart.

Comment: You could try to verify on the server if you get those two requests and if both are handled properly Only the first needs to return the AccessControlAllowOrigin headers but doesn't hurt on the others.

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer could you pass me the url for the article above? cannot find it, sorry

Comment: verification in Server: something fails, php seems not active, and the browser echo's the whole php script.

Comment: What article? Is this still relevant?

Comment: No, your first answer would have solved all my problems, if I had not had this <?php problem in the server source. txs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server needs to add the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header not the client.

Your page is initally load from `http://127.0.0.1:3030` and then wants to access `http://127.0.0.1/dartphp/index.php` which is considered a different domain.

The client sends a request to the server to check if it responds with a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header that fits the clients origin (which `*` as wildcard does) after this the actual request is sent.

Try setting the following headers

```
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://127.0.0.1:3030"
"Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS"
```

Comment: substituted the header in php with the 2 new headers, same result.

Comment: some colleague played a bad trick on me: turned off the <?php short-cut!!!!! But thanks for your explanation about WHO sends Cors-headers, was absolutely unclear to me